# drush @sites command doesn't work

Tags: 8, drush, multi-sites

The command `drush @sites status` doesn't do anything.

The full command obtained for the process is:

> `/usr/bin/php /home/myuser/.config/composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php --php-options= @sites status`

This is my enviroment:

- Drupal:  8.2.4
- Drush:  8.1.7

The "**drush site-alias**" command says me:

- @site1
- @none
- @site2
- @self
- default
- site1
- site2

I have a setup for Drupal multi-sites with subdirectories, the aliases file is:

**~/.drush/aliases.drushrc.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Site alias for all sites
 */
$root = '/var/www/html';

$aliases['site1'] = array(
    'uri' => 'multisite.local/site1',
    'root' => $root,
    'path-aliases' => array(
        '%dump-dir' => '/tmp'
    ),
);
$aliases['site2'] = array(
    'uri' => 'multisite.local/site2',
    'root' => $root,
    'path-aliases' => array(
        '%dump-dir' => '/tmp'
    ),
);
```

The full output of the **drush status** command is:

```
 Drupal version                  :  8.2.4
 Site URI                        :  http://default
 Database driver                 :  mysql
 Database hostname               :  localhost
 Database port                   :  3306
 Database username               :  db_user
 Database name                   :  db_name
 Database                        :  Connected
 Drupal bootstrap                :  Successful
 Drupal user                     :
 Default theme                   :  bootstrap
 Administration theme            :  seven
 PHP executable                  :  /usr/bin/php
 PHP configuration               :  /etc/php.ini
 PHP OS                          :  Linux
 Drush script                    :  /home/myuser/.config/composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php
 Drush version                   :  8.1.7
 Drush temp directory            :  /tmp
 Drush configuration             :
 Drush alias files               :  /home/myuser/.drush/aliases.drushrc.php
 Install profile                 :  standard
 Drupal root                     :  /var/www/html
 Drupal Settings File            :  sites/default/settings.php
 Site path                       :  sites/default
 File directory path             :  sites/default/files
 Private file directory path     :  private/default
 Temporary file directory path   :  /tmp
 Sync config path                :  sites/default/files/config_BrLQsjBr6VkcTEyCkzkY-es-hzISWg4d3oV2EEEoqh-UZMLBJWDiDaq78TIWm-lBbVi-aPHISw/sync
```

Comment: Just to be 100% sure: You are running ```drush site-alias``` and ```drush @sites status``` in the same directory/inside your Drupal root (/var/www/html)? I just tested on a multisite D7 installation with Drush 8.1.8 and ```drush @sites status``` works - the status command is executed for all sites in the multisite.

Comment: @hansfn Yes it is from the DocumentRoot of Apache and the Drupal root directory(_/var/www/html_). I left the process running for about 5 minutes, but nothing happened...

Answer (score -1):

"@sites" is no longer available with Drush 9. I presume this what is being used with Drupal 8 here.

More information here:
https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/3019#issuecomment-334503217

> Drush 9 no longer supports executing a single command on multiple sites with alias lists (@A,@b,@c) or @sites. Neither of those syntaxes are available in any context. You may still use drush sa @group to see all aliases in a group; that is the only context in which Drush recognizes alias lists.

Comment: OP asked for Drush 8. For Drush 9 this already got answered here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250688/drush-sites-not-implemented-in-drush-9