# Use drush to install a module on all of the sites of a multisite at once

Tags: drush, installation, multi-sites

I have a Drupal 8 multisite, setup with 6 different sites.  I want to install Admin Toolbar on all of them on my local dev environment (mamp / terminal / drush).  I have downloaded that module using composer:

```
composer require drupal/admin_toolbar
```

Is there a single drush command that will install this module on all six of the sites at once?  If not, what is the most efficient way to install it to each?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drush @sites not implemented in drush 9](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250688/drush-sites-not-implemented-in-drush-9)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using **Acquia Cloud Site Factory (ACSF)** then you can use ACSF command `acsf-tools-ml`

   **acsf-tools-ml (sfml)**: This command will run any Drush command against all sites in your factory. `drush @coolsites.01dev sfml en admin_toolbar`

2. **Other solution:** It's not recommended to enable/disable module directly on the server in this way you lose access to Configuration management.(It will become difficult to manage it)

Recommended Approach:

- Enable module in your local environment and then export it via `drush config:export`
- import the configuration on the respected server via `drush  config:import`
- You can write a simple bash command to automate drush  config:import on all the websites.

Comment: Oops, I should have said that I was working on a local dev environment.